# AS3: Vectors doesnt rezise when i resize my MovieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have bit of a strange problem. In have a MovieClip i resize, but the vector graphic doesn't resize with it. It's a Movieclip in my library that i'm linking to and when I insert it on my stage, it resizes just fine.

I have exported the MovieClip as an AS Object called: `TabTemplate` and the i extend it in a class called `Tab`.

I set some text in the textfield defined in it and the resize the tab accordingly. but the graphic doesnt follow :(

I'm not used to AS3's ways of doing things, so there might be something i've missed.

Here's the class code:

```
package mypackage {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class Tab extends TabTemplate {
        function Tab() {
        }

        /*** Getters/Setters ***/
        public function set text( value:String ):void {
            this.tabname.wordWrap = false;
            this.tabname.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            this.tabname.text = value;
            this.tabname.y = (this.mcMask.height - this.tabname.textHeight) /2;
            this.tabname.x = this.tabname.y;
            this.width = this.tabname.width + (this.tabname.x *2);

            // I want to avoide to resize this after resizing the MovieClip
            //this.mcMask.width = this.width; 
        }

        public function get text():String {
            return this.tabname.text;
        }
    }
}
```

There is actually two issues going on here:

1) The `textWidth` isn't return the correct number. I have some shadow on the text and i don't know if that screws anything up. But otherwise I'm just using Regular Arial.

2) The mask of the 'Tab' + it's vector background isn't resizing when I'm resizing the MovieClip, like it does in Flash it self.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: I've tried your trick for reading the `textWidth`, but it just returns the same number, so that didn't help unfortunately.

@heartcodes: your suggestion might work, but it's the thing i wanted to avoid.

Comment: Sounds to me like there is something wrong with your TabTemplate. Can you post its code and/or a link to an SWF that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @weltraumpirat: TabTmplate is actually just a precreated MovieClip, that i export as a class `TabTemplate` from the library, there is nothing more to it actually. I then just extend it with the `Tab` class. So basically it should just be a MovieClip with predefined content i extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must have obviously gone wrong with your TabTemplate.  Maybe it is better to start from scratch.

I have set up a class that does not extend TabTemplate, but has an instance of it as a member.  This way, you'll get to separate the text and the graphics, but should be able to make the clip resize as a whole, instead of resizing its parts separately.

Two things are important for this to work:

1. You will have to remove the textfield from TabTemplate.  It will be generated dynamically.  If you want to use embedded fonts, you'll have to take care of embedding the font style and setting the TextFormat; I did not put any such code in there.
2. You cannot use 9-slice-scaling with vector masks.  If you have a mask that requires 9-slice-scaling, you will need to change the way your graphics are set up, or create a drawing mechanism in ActionScript (for example, if you want rounded corners) that refreshes when the text has been set.

Here's the code:

```
package mypackage {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class Tab extends MovieClip {
        private var background : TabTemplate = new TabTemplate();
        private var tabname : TextField = new TextField ();

        public function set text( value:String ):void {
            tabname.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
            tabname.multiline = tabname.wordWrap = false;
            tabname.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            tabname.text = value;
            tabname.y = (background.height - tabname.textHeight) *.5;
            tabname.x = tabname.y;
            addChild (tabname);

            background.width = tabname.width + (tabname.x *2);
            addChildAt (background, 0);
        }

        public function get text():String {
            return tabname.text;
        }
    }
}
```

See if this works for you.  If not, let me know if you get any error messages, and let's go on from there.

Comment: Hey thaks for that answer. I used this.tabname.width because it didn't read the textWidth correctly. But your answer just might help me. However it doesn't help my other problem with the vector graphic not resizing.

Comment: I rewrote my answer.  I think it would be best to start from scratch, to figure out the problem.  You can copy your TabTemplate to a new FLA to try this out, and merge it back into your main FLA later.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tried to remove the mask and the text and it worked! so it was the mask that was f***ing things up :) now i just need to make it position the text correctly, but that another question :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
this.tabname.width

Try
this.tabname.textWidth

Maybe it helps.

I believe you shouldn't set the width of the whole Tab (you also resize the textfield as well), only the background (or any graphical) elements in the TabTemplate class. As you extend this class you will have access to these instances.

Rob

Comment: I don't like your tone of voice mr. 5k

Comment: Tokimon, I upsated my answer, i hope it helps.

Comment: @heartcode: Sorry, didn't mean to offend you.  Still: If what I believe is right, textWidth will return the same result as width, minus the padding. It will not solve the autoSize problem.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comments. I might be able to use your answer @heartcode but i was hoping to avoid reszing every element inside the MovieClip. Isn't there an easier way to resize the MovieClip AND the elements inside. Just like when you resize it inside the Flash program?

Comment: @weltraumpirat No worries dude :)